# Why am I unable to decouple the size of a span from the parent div when setting the span as a larger width?

Tags: html, css

Relevant Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/promexj1/1/

I am attempting to set the two child spans within the parent div with set widths slightly smaller than the parent div (since I am starting the translation 10px to the right for the verse-one span).
However I notice when rendering these spans in the DOM they revert back to half of the parent div's size (possibly because there are two of the spans).

Note I put the black border on the span elements to visualize their size

How might I decouple this inherited size divided among the child spans and instead force the spans to be rendered based on their styling widths?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
        }

        body {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            background: #333;
            font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        }

        .scrollable_section {
            width: 125px;
            overflow-x: auto;
            overflow-y: hidden;
            white-space: nowrap;
            scrollbar-width: none;
            border: #000 1px solid;
        }

        .scrollable_section::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
        }

        .field {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
            width: 150px;
            height: 16px;
            background-color: red;
            overflow: hidden;
            white-space: nowrap;
            transition: all 1s;
        }

        .verse-one {
            color: white;
            opacity: 1;
            transform: translateX(10px);
            transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s 0.5s;
        }

        .verse-two {
            color: #000;
            opacity: 0;
            transform: translateX(200px);
            transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s 0.5s;
        }

        .next-verse {
            background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        }

        .next-verse .verse-one {
            opacity: 0;
            transform: translateX(-200px);
        }

        .next-verse .verse-two {
            opacity: 1;
            transform: translateX(-65px);
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="toggleTransition()">Toggle Transition</button>
    <div class="field" id="example">
        <span class="verse-one scrollable_section">
            I am the very model of a modern major general.
            Ive information vegetable animal and mineral.
            I know the kings of england and quote the fights historical
            from marathon to waterloo in order categorical.

        </span>
        <span class="verse-two scrollable_section">
            I am very well acquainted too with matters mathematical.
            I understand equations both the simple and quadratical.
            About binomial theorem I am teeming with a lot of news.
            With many cheerful facts about the square of the hypotenuse.
        </span>
    </div>



    <script>
        function toggleTransition() {
            var example = document.getElementById('example');
            example.classList.toggle('next-verse');
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since those spans live in a flex container, you may use `flex-shrink: 0` to mantain their fixed size.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink

> The flex-shrink CSS property sets the flex shrink factor of a flex
> item. If the size of all flex items is larger than the flex container,
> items shrink to fit according to flex-shrink.

To accomodate this quick solution to your demo I just added that property to the rule for `.scrollable_section` and changed the `translateX` value for `.verse-two`. But it wasn't perfectly clear how you were dealing with the text overflow so it's not perfectly focused on that part of the problem:

```js
function toggleTransition() {
  var example = document.getElementById('example');
  example.classList.toggle('next-verse');
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #333;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.scrollable_section {
  width: 125px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  border: #000 1px solid;
  
  flex-shrink: 0; /* added */
}

.scrollable_section::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.field {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.verse-one {
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(10px);
  transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s 0.5s;
}

.verse-two {
  color: #000;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(200px);
  transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s 0.5s;
}

.next-verse {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.next-verse .verse-one {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-200px);
}

.next-verse .verse-two {
  opacity: 1;  
  transform: translateX(-115px); /* changed from -65px */
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button onclick="toggleTransition()">Toggle Transition</button>
  <div class="field" id="example">
    <span class="verse-one scrollable_section">
            I am the very model of a modern major general.
            Ive information vegetable animal and mineral.
            I know the kings of england and quote the fights historical
            from marathon to waterloo in order categorical.
        </span>
    <span class="verse-two scrollable_section">
            I am very well acquainted too with matters mathematical.
            I understand equations both the simple and quadratical.
            About binomial theorem I am teeming with a lot of news.
            With many cheerful facts about the square of the hypotenuse.
        </span>
  </div>
</body>
```